# calculating upper case letters ,lowercase letters, and other characters

Tags: jes

Write a program that accepts a sentence as console input and calculate the number of upper case letters , lower case letters and other characters.

Suppose the following input is supplied to the program:
Hello World;!#

Comment: In what programming language ?  Ah, "jes" (the tag) or Python too I guess.

Comment: Yes, using jes. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question sounds like a programming assignment, I've written this is a more-wordy manner.  This is standard Python 3, not Jes.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys

upper_case_chars = 0
lower_case_chars = 0
total_chars = 0
found_eof = False

# Read character after character from stdin, processing it in turn
# Stop if an error is encountered, or End-Of-File happens.
while (not found_eof):
    try:
        letter = str(sys.stdin.read(1))
    except:
        # handle any I/O error somewhat cleanly
        break

    if (letter != ''):
        total_chars += 1
        if (letter >= 'A' and letter <= 'Z'):
            upper_case_chars += 1
        elif (letter >= 'a' and letter <= 'z'):
            lower_case_chars += 1
    else:
        found_eof = True

# write the results to the console
print("Upper-case Letters: %3u" % (upper_case_chars))
print("Lower-case Letters: %3u" % (lower_case_chars))
print("Other Letters:      %3u" % (total_chars - (upper_case_chars + lower_case_chars)))
```

Note that you should modify the code to handle end-of-line characters yourself.  Currently they're counted as "other".  I've also left out handling of binary input, *probably* the str() will fail.